# CakePHP Sort order not affecting all records

Tags: mysql, sorting, cakephp, cakephp-2.x, cakephp-2.7

In my CakePHP 2.7.7 app, I have an issue where using PaginatorComponent isn't properly sorting my results. See this link for an image:
[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyxpI.png)

The data should be sorted by descending last name, but you can see there are a couple users who are seemingly exempt from this data. Doesn't matter what order I do it in, ascending or descending, these few records don't get sorted. For reference:

index() in UsersController:

```
public function index() {
    $this->User->contain('Status');
    $this->paginate = array(
        'limit' => 15,
        'order' => array('User.last_name' => 'DESC'),
        'conditions' => array('User.department_id =' => $this->Session->read('Auth.User.department_id')),
        'contain' => 'Status'
    );
    $this->set('users', $this->Paginator->paginate());
}
```

Any ideas what could have caused this? I'm at a loss here. Thanks in advance!

```
SELECT `User`.`id`, `User`.`first_name`, `User`.`last_name`, `User`.`middle`, `User`.`address`, `User`.`address_2`, `User`.`city`, `User`.`state_id`, `User`.`zip`, `User`.`home`, `User`.`cell`, `User`.`work`, `User`.`email`, `User`.`status_id`, `User`.`status_reason`, `User`.`rank`, `User`.`birthday`, `User`.`gender`, `User`.`school`, `User`.`employer`, `User`.`position`, `User`.`created`, `User`.`modified`, `User`.`updated_by`, `User`.`radio`, `User`.`ident`, `User`.`parent_name`, `User`.`parent_number`, `User`.`parent_email`, `User`.`squad`, `User`.`squad_leader`, `User`.`ride_along`, `User`.`drivers_license`, `User`.`username`, `User`.`password`, `User`.`department_id`, `User`.`join_date`, `User`.`group_id`, `User`.`test`, (CONCAT(`User`.`first_name`, " ", `User`.`last_name`)) AS `User__name`, `Status`.`id`, `Status`.`status` FROM `admin_cake`.`users` AS `User` LEFT JOIN `admin_cake`.`statuses` AS `Status` ON (`User`.`status_id` = `Status`.`id`) WHERE `User`.`department_id` = 1 ORDER BY `User`.`last_name` ASC LIMIT 15
```

Comment: What is the SQL query generated for this?

Comment: Make sure that the last names don't have a leading space.

Comment: @drmonkeyninja I've updated the question with a sample query.

Comment: @InigoFlores I thought the same, but I can't seem to find any records with an extra space.

Comment: @Jason your SQL looks correct. If you run this query directly on the database do you get the desired result or is this incorrect? If the query is failing this question may be better reworded as a MySQL problem rather than a Cake one.

Comment: @drmonkeyninja I just assumed MySQL was working, but when I ran that query in phpMyAdmin the issue became painfully clear. The `last_name` column is encrypted, and therefore the `ORDER BY` was alphabetically sorting the encrypted data, not the actual last names. Now to figure out how to sort after decryption...

Answer (score 0):

When you use $this->paginate to set conditions, limit...you need to use function $this->pagination().
$this->pagination and $this->Paginator->pagination() can not be combined.

1)

```
public function index() {
    $this->User->contain('Status');
    $this->paginate = array(
        'limit' => 15,
        'order' => array('User.last_name' => 'DESC'),
        'conditions' => array('User.department_id =' => $this->Session->read('Auth.User.department_id')),
        'contain' => 'Status'
    );
    // Assign settings
    $this->Paginator->settings = $this->paginate;
    $this->set('users', $this->Paginator->paginate());
}
```

2)

```
public function index() {
    $this->User->contain('Status');
    $this->paginate = array(
        'limit' => 15,
        'order' => array('User.last_name' => 'DESC'),
        'conditions' => array('User.department_id =' => $this->Session->read('Auth.User.department_id')),
        'contain' => 'Status'
    );
    //Don't use $this->Paginator->paginate()
    $this->set('users', $this->paginate());
}
```

Comment: I had `$this->paginate()` originally but had mixed up `$this->Paginator->paginate()` with some other things I was trying. I switched it back and get the same result.